# Unix & Shell Programming: the "test" built-in and spaces on the command line

Tags: shell, unix, command-line, space

this is my first time asking question in stackoverflow.
I just started Unix course in this term, and I got pretty confusing about "Space" key in command line. Here are some examples:

```
% set x1="005"
% test "$x1" = 5
% echo $status
1
```

The second line I got space key after "$x1" and before 5, and I got result back as 1, which is correct because they are two different string. But if I type my command like this:

```
% set x1="005"
% test "$x1"=5
% echo $status
0
```

As you can see, in second line, there are no space after "$x1" and before 5, but the test result back to 0, which is they are same. I have no idea why this happened. Because when I do JAVA or C++, space really doesn't have influence like this. 
I know this might be dumb, but still hope you guys can help me understand this, thank you very much and have a nice day :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the shell, *word splitting* is performed at spaces. So the first `test` sees three arguments, `005`, `=`, and `5`. If called with these three arguments, `test` treats the second as an operator, and the first and third as operands.

However, `test "$x1"=5` becomes `test 005=5` after parameter expansion and quote removal. Since there are no spaces, no further word-splitting is performed (except between `test` and its single argument).

With just one argument, `test` checks for an non-empty argument, which in this case is true.

Here's the relevant quote from the [POSIX Standard about `test`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/test.html):

> In the following list, $1, $2, $3, and $4 represent the arguments
>   presented to test:
>
> **0 arguments:**
>       Exit false (1).
>
> **1 argument:**
>       Exit true (0) if $1 is not null; otherwise, exit false.
>
> **2 arguments:**
>
> If $1 is '!', exit true if $2 is null, false if $2 is not null.
>
> If $1 is a unary primary, exit true if the unary test is true,
>     false if the unary test is false.
>
> Otherwise, produce unspecified results.
>
> **3 arguments:**
>
> If $2 is a binary primary, perform the binary test of $1 and $3.
>
> If $1 is '!', negate the two-argument test of $2 and $3.
>
> [OB XSI] [Option Start] If $1 is '(' and $3 is ')', perform the unary test of $2. [Option End]
>     On systems that do not support the
>     XSI option, the results are unspecified if $1 is '(' and $3 is ')'.
>
> Otherwise, produce unspecified results.
>
> **4 arguments:**
>
> If $1 is '!', negate the three-argument test of $2, $3, and $4.
>
> [OB XSI] [Option Start] If $1 is '(' and $4 is ')', perform the two-argument test of $2 and $3. [Option End]  On systems that do
>   not support the XSI option, the results are unspecified if $1 is '('
>   and $4 is ')'.
>
> Otherwise, the results are unspecified.
>
> **>4 arguments:**
>       The results are unspecified.

Comment: Thank you very much Jens, really help a lot! :)

Answer (score 1):

The first passes the arguments "005", "=", and "5" to `test`. This tests if the strings are equal, which they are not. The second passes the single argument "005=5" to `test`. The behavior of `test` when passed a single argument is to treat it as a string and to test that it is non-empty. And yes, that is a non-empty string.